# Does Rock Band 3's song rating system change the recommendations?

Tags: rock-band-3

Rock Band 3 added two new features: song ratings and recommendations.  The song ratings, as far as I know, just change the likelihood of songs showing up.  The recommendations, as far as I know, are the same for every user.

I was curious if RB3 uses these for [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) - in the same way that when you rate movies on Netflix it gives you different movie recommendations.  Does anyone know if this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What it says in-game for the lighter ratings is:

- 5 is twice as likely to appear in random setlists
- 4 is 50% more likely to appear in random setlists
- 3 standard (equivalent to no rating at all)
- 2 is 50% less likely
- 1 will not appear in a random setlist unless there is no other choice

Comment: That's all well and good, I'm just curious if the ratings also affect song recommendations for the music store.

Comment: @daniel I am sure it does. The inline DLC recommendations (they appear as green shaded rows in the song selection screens) are new to RB3 and surely would build off the same system..

Comment: The inline recommendations may just be the same for everyone, or maybe they're based on previous purchases rather than ratings (ala Amazon).  As a result I cannot draw a confident conclusion from the evidence thus far.